# Limitations of Twisted code reloading

Tags: python, twisted

I'm building an XML-RPC server using Twisted which periodically checks if the timestamps of its source files have changed and reloads them using `rebuild`.

```
from twisted.python.rebuild import rebuild

rebuild(mymodule)
```

The functions the server exposes get reloaded fine, but there in another protocol class active which calls callback functions on the same class of `mymodule` but they don't use the reloaded version of the functions. This protocol simply has a `dict` with normal functions as values.

I found this mixin class which is intended to deal with limitations of `rebuild`.

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.python.rebuild.Sensitive.html

How do I make sure my callbacks use up to date code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct; this is a limitation of `twisted.python.rebuild`.  It's on updating the `__class__` attribute of existing instances, and imported functions and classes.

One way to deal with this would be to simply [submit a patch to Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/newticket) that fixes `rebuild` for this case.

However, if you want to use `Sensitive` for its intended purpose, you can also implement your callback-holding class to work with `rebuild` on current versions of Twisted.  The following examples demonstrates how to use all three methods of the relevant class to update a dictionary of callbacks pointing at functions.  Note that even without the `if needRebuildUpdate...` test, calling `x()` directly will always get the most up-to-date version.

```
from twisted.python.rebuild import rebuild, Sensitive
from twisted.python.filepath import FilePath

p = FilePath("mymodule.py")
def clearcache():
    bytecode = p.sibling("mymodule.pyc")
    if bytecode.exists():
        bytecode.remove()
clearcache()
p.setContent("def x(): return 1")
import mymodule
from mymodule import x
p.setContent("def x(): return 2")

class Something(Sensitive, object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stuff = {"something": x}
    def invoke(self):
        if self.needRebuildUpdate():
            for key in list(self.stuff):
                self.stuff[key] = self.latestVersionOf(self.stuff[key])
            self.rebuildUpToDate()
        return self.stuff["something"]()

def test():
    print s.invoke()
    print x()

s = Something()
test()

clearcache()
rebuild(mymodule)

test()
```